# How to: remove cached results by Google

Tags: html

Google is still displaying results for pages that have been removed from a website of created by me a while ago, and linking to the website.

Anyone know how long it takes for these results to disappear from Google?

Comment: You can find a quite detailed article on how to remove a website or a page from Google search results from here - http://www.edicy.com/blog/how-to-remove-your-website-or-web-page-from-google. Take care!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it could take up to several weeks. Once every 1-2 weeks or so Google will attempt to reindex your website and if it finds a dead end it will remove it.

P.S. If i remember correctly there was a link where you could request Google to index your website and that might speed the removal process.

EDIT:

try the following link from google webmasters

> http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164734

Comment: Thanks! I've requested a url removal :)